# Nightwatch - button click using button text name

Tags: html, css, automation, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

Is there any way to click the button using button text?

`<label class="button"><span>Button 1</span></label>
<label class="button"><span>Button 2</span></label>
<label class="button"><span>Button 3</span></label>
<label class="button"><span>Button 4</span></label>`

I currently use `:nth-of-type` to locate them but I'm looking for something more readable. (Xpath also not very readable).

The other option I'm thinking about, to use page objects and move not readable selector there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS selectors do not currently support matching text, and probably never will. You can use xpath to locate the button by its text.

/* This will match any button that *contains* the string 'Button 1'. If there were say, a Button 12, Nightwatch will complain about multiple elements matching that selector, but it will generally work. */

```
.useXpath().click("//*[contains(text(),'Button 1')]")
```

/* 
 This will match only a button that *exactly matches* the string 'Button 1'*/

`.useXpath().click("//*[.='Button 1']")` 
// Note that spaces matter, so if there is a leading or trailing space in the html, or anything else, it won't work.

/* Finally, let's say your buttons aren't numbered, like this html:*/

```
<button class="astext"><span>Foo</span></button>
<button class="astext"><span>Foo</span></button>
<button class="astext"><span>Foo</span></button>
<button class="astext"><span>Foo</span></button>
```

/* you still have options here. by indexing into the item you want. Let's assume you want to click the second button with the text "Foo". To do that, wrap your xpath expression in parenthesis, and then note your index in brackets like this:*/

```
.useXpath().click("(//*[contains(text(),'Foo')])[2]")
```

xpath selectors are worth knowing. There are times when it's just far simpler to write an xpath selector and with practice, it's reasonably easy to do. [Here is an excellent source document on xpath selectors](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf)